# Calling Microsoft web service no response in the first time

Tags: objective-c, web-services

I have through below script to connect my Microsoft web service to insert some record to database, everyday in the morning when i back to office, in the first time i run below script it is not work normally, it look like no response from the web service but the connection is fine, but when i run the script again second time, the result is fine. (found some record inserted to database)

It look like the web service was sleep at night, when i run the script first time, just wake up the web service, when i run the script second time then the web service is working fine.

Any one have idea about this situation? thanks.

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance>\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema>\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/>\">\n"
                                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                                         " <Ins_VIP xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/>\">\n"
                                         "<strVIPNo>%@</strVIPNo>\n"
                                         "</Ins_VIP>\n"
                                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                                         "</soap:Envelope>\n" , strVIPNo];


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.1/VIPWebService/service1.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/Ins_VIP" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];


if( theConnection )
{
   NSLog(@"No Problem");
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
```

Comment: You need to do some debugging at the server end to determine what is happening.

Comment: Can you track the HTTP calls and see whats the status for the First failed call ? If it has succeeded in communicating with server it will be 200. You can use Charles app to monitor network activity.